# Replace Second Instance of String

Tags: php, string, instance

I just wondering how I could replace the second instance of a string inside a string in php such as follows:

```
a - b - c
```

Where it woulld add an extra space after the second "`-`" but only if it finds 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$finds = explode('-', "a - b - c");
if (count($finds) == 3) {
  $finds[2] = " {$finds[2]}";
}

$finds = implode('-', $finds);
```

Comment: +1 -- Posted the same reply (now deleted) but way too late :). You want to correct your last line though. like, $result=implode("-",$finds);

Comment: haha yea, i already had to edit bc i missed the 2nd arg in explode lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str ="a - b - c";    
if (substr_count($str,"-")>2){
  print preg_replace("/^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)/","\\1-\\2- \\3",$str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**// User Function to replace string by Occurance**

function str_occ_replace($from,$to,$subject,$occ){
    $myArray = explode($from,$subject);
    print_r($myArray);
    $mystring = '';
    $index = 1;
    foreach($myArray as $ele){

        if($index !== $occ AND $index !== $arraySize)
            $mystring .= $ele.$from;
        else if($index !== $arraySize)
            $mystring .= $ele.$to;
        $index++;
    } // End of Foreach
    return $mystring;
} // End of Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Substring the string starting at the index of the first dash using `strpos` then do a `str_replace` on the rest of the string. Concatenate the two together.